# G++ 4.8.2 insists simple variable members are arrays

Tags: c++, gcc

This problem only occurs with g++ 4.8.2 for ARMv6 (stock pidora); it compiles without error or warning on x86_64 w/ clang 3.4.2 and g++ 4.8.3.  I am having a hard time not seeing it as a compiler bug, but wanted to get some other opinions.

It involves a simple member variable that g++ keeps insisting is an array and

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

The header for the class looks like this:

```
namespace SystemStateMonitor {

class ramInput : public input, public inputFile {
        public:
                typedef enum {
                        RATIO,
                        PERCENT,
                        KiBYTES,
                        MiBYTES
                } style_t;
                ramInput (
                        const std::string &label = "RAM",
                        style_t style = style_t::PERCENT
                );
                unsigned int getAvailable ();
                double getDV ();
                double ratio ();
        protected:
                style_t style;
                unsigned int available;
                void setStyle (style_t);
        friend input* jsonInputRAM (jsonObject);
};

}
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
#define PROC_FILE "/proc/meminfo"

using namespace std;
using namespace SystemStateMonitor;

ramInput::ramInput (
        const string &label,
        ramInput::style_t s
) :
        input (label),
        inputFile (PROC_FILE),
        style (s),
        available (0)
{
        setStyle(style);
}
```

And when I compile this with the ARMv6 g++, I get:

```
inputs/ramInput.cpp:19:14: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
  available (0)
              ^
```

The superclasses do not have any member "available"; there is no potential weird collision. Interestingly, if I then modify the constructor:

```
) :
        input (label),
        inputFile (PROC_FILE),
        style (s)
{
        available = 0;
        setStyle(style);
}
```

I now get the same error for `style (s)`.  If I then do the same thing with `style` (move initialization into the body), *I get the error for `inputFile (PROC_FILE)`,* which is even more bizarre because that's a super constructor call.

```
inputs/ramInput.cpp:17:22: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
  inputFile (PROC_FILE)
                      ^
```

Unfortunately but not surprisingly, an SSCCE starting with this:

```
class test {
        public:
                test () : x(0) { };
                unsigned int x;
};
```

Does not reproduce the problem.

What could be going wrong here?  Am I right to believe this isn't my fault?

Comment: Try adding **#undef available** before your constructor.  It could possibly be a macro in one of your include files

Comment: I tried to create a test case that didn't depend on headers that you aren't providing. Does https://gist.github.com/sharth/e8cfee2603594fe64dee still fail for you?

Comment: Could you post the output of `g++ -E systemstatemonitor.cpp`? It's long so you might be forced to use gist.github.com or similar instead of inlining it in your question.

Comment: By removing the initailisations of `style` and `available`, you're on the right track to making an SSCCE. If you could provide (minimal) definitions of the base classes, and remove anything else that's not needed to cause the error, then maybe we could figure out what's going on. Unless the compiler is completely broken, your real code contains an array, while the posted code doesn't.

Comment: The confusing positioning of the error after the last item in the initialiser list just means there's a problem somewhere in the list, not that the last item is the problem. That's why the problem remains when you remove the last item.

Comment: @BillLynch Sorry -- forgot to include the appropriate include path.  Removed the old one and the correct one [is here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109399080/SSM.txt), from `g++ -E --std=c++11 ...`

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever: I'm sorry. I may have accidentally confused you. I actually want the output of `g++ -E inputs/ramInput.cpp` (with whatever other appropriate compiler flags). I thought the file causing the compiler error was named that. Sorry!

Comment: @BillLynch Okay, [that's this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109399080/ramInput.txt).

Comment: Actually that one's been modified as per the post -- with the initialization of `available` and `style` moved into the constructor body.

Comment: @BillLynch Okay, I found it.  The `input` superclass default initialized an array like this `std::array<double,2> range = { 0 }`, which that gcc evidently does not like; I have to use `{ }` (and get a missing-field-initializers warning...).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yep -- see above.

Answer (score 3):

As Mike Seymour points out in comments on the question, the cascading nature of the error indicated the compiler was simply pointing to the end of the problem initialization list, rather than the correct entry. The array turned out to be in a superclass constructor default initializer:

```
   std::array<double,2> range = { 0 }
```

That particular g++ chokes on that, and:

```
   std::array<double,2> range = { 0.0, 0.0 }
```

But:

```
   std::array<double,2> range = { }
```

Works.  Good thing I didn't want any non-zero values there...